# Is my AliExpress "Member Profile" data public or private?

Tags: privacy, profile, aliexpress

I'm an AliExpress user. Is my profile data (that appears in the URL: https://accounts.aliexpress.com/user/organization/manage_person_profile.htm after successful login) private or public? I'm confused since it seems to be different than "shipping data". I attached an image of the web page for clarification.

[image: Member Profile]

Text:

> ### Edit Member Profile
>
> Name:
> Gender:
> Email Address: (Email address confirmed)
> Member ID:
> Contact Address:
> Zip/Postal Code:
> Tel:
> Fax: